# bash : huge loop on simple and big array, bug on the last element + memory leak

Tags: bash

On the last element of an array of strings, the script hangs, uses 100% cpu and memory gets more than 500MB, and more ....
The array size is 1406
Bash is 4.3 (old server)
Does someone know this bug ?

```
# get sorted values (strings) of the associative array to build a simple array
final=($(for k in "${!namefiles_servers[@]}"; do echo $k===${namefiles_servers[$k]}; done | sort))
for val in "${final[@]}"; do
... 
# at the 1406th element, the last statement of the loop is executed and the script hangs
done
```

Comment: this does not provide enough information to allow us to understand your problem, since we don't see what you are doing inside your loop.

Comment: only string manipulations, variables expansions, substitutions, appending, etc ...   
please note that this works with 10, 50, 100, etc elements, but not here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a lot more information about your problem, preferably the entire section of the script where the problem occurs. We need to know what you're doing in the loop, since it might be caused by some program..

However, here's some information about speeding up your script. If it has something to do with too much resources, you can optimize your script easily.

For big problems, certainly when you're using a slow (but loved) language as bash, it's better to store your data in a file than use them all in one for loop. That's because the for loop holds the entire array, whereas using the code below parses the file line-by-line. Of course, if you have separate blocks of data, you need to delimit it with read its `-d` option or something.

```
# sort your file here
while read -r line; do
    #something
done < ${MYIFLE}
```

Another thing that might cause a problem is supplying entire arrays to functions, such as:

```
function test_array_1 {
        local arr=($@)
        sleep 1
        (for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done)>/dev/null
}
```

It's better to pass a reference to it, because it would neglect a copy. This makes the script much faster.

```
function test_array_2 {
        local -n arr=$1
        sleep 1
        (for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done)>/dev/null
}
```

A copy would take the script below around 3 minutes, whereas the reference takes 44 seconds. You can test it yourself.

```
#! /bin/bash

function test_array_1 {
        local arr=($@)
        sleep 1
        (for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done)>/dev/null
}

function test_array_2 {
        local -n arr=$1
        sleep 1
        (for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done)>/dev/null
}

test_function=$1

ARR=$(seq 1 10000000)

if [ "${test_function}" = "test_array_1" ]; then 
        time test_array_1 ${ARR[@]} &
elif [ "${test_function}" = "test_array_2" ]; then
        time test_array_2 ARR &
fi
wait
exit 0
```

EDIT: 
Thinking about this some more, why do you need two arrays? Since the arrays equal in amount of entries, you can rewrite your for loop and make the `final` array redundant.

```
#! /bin/bash
# This array represents random data, which you seem to have. Otherwise, don't 
# sort at all 
namefiles_servers=("$(seq 1 100 | sort -R)")

# You can sort it as such, no need for loops.
namefiles_servers=($(echo "${namefiles_servers[@]}" | sort))

# And access it with a loop. ${#namefiles_servers[@]} is the number of 
# elements in your array
for ((i=0; i<${#namefiles_servers[@]}; i++)); do
        echo index $i has value ${namefiles_servers[$i]}
done
```

Comment: :( too long to paste the code in a comment Bayou

Comment: Too bad :-( Try to optimize your code guided by my answer and I think you will be able to solve it. Good luck!

Comment: please see here Bayou https://paste.ee/p/OEe8G   
you can see a final[] element in the comment   
same issue with centos6/bash 4.1.2

Comment: Oh my. I will take a look at this at home if that's okay with you. I'll try to optimize it as much as possible, but I don't have the time for it now.

Comment: ok thanks Bayou, only if you can :)   
and same issue with ksh : at the last statement of the loop (just before 'done'), which is executed, the shell hangs and memory leaks .. as if the last iteration were not seen by the for loop

Comment: Can you supply a part or variant on the data that's being processed? I would like to mimic a real world scenario.

Comment: the simple array 'final' contains strings like :     
tools_mutu===/LOCAL/system/service/etc/etc/tools/dispatchers/bsh_hca/ftp-bsh-s5===+erfshs01s+erfshs02s     
so the layout is :  name===filepath===servers+...     
here these data are extracted from a real filesystem     
but it's easy to generate via a loop 2.000 elements with the same name, incremental filepath names and same servers no ? :)

Comment: wait Bayou, i'm going to optimize the code ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197509/discussion-between-bayou-and-minstrel).

Comment: **Here is the explanation** : the $json is a huge string (~500KB), and when I write   
`if test $json = ....` 
bash does a globbing action, fetching all IFS (space by def) among other things, and needs to allocate memory    
To protect it from that, the fix is to write `if test "$json" = ...`, so with double quotes 
  
you can test yourself this huge memory comsuption :    

`
#!/bin/bsh  
# myfile contains a 500KB string on one line   
read myvar <myfile      
if test $myvar = "whatever"; then :; fi   
`